# Swift Alamofire check wait timeout and put error

Tags: swift, xcode, settimeout, alamofire

I use the Alamofire for get data from REST api.

```
                Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
                .authenticate(user: user, password: password)
                .responseString { response in
                    if (response.result.error != nil)
                    {
                        show_error()
                    }
                }
                .response { (request, response, data, error) in ...
```

I get and put error, if user don't have internet connection. And I want to put error if user wait more than 3 second response after request.

How cat I make it? How use timeout in the Alamofire?

Answer (score 3):

```
Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 3000
```

This applies to all requests. If you only want to set the timeout for one specific request:

```
let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
sessionManager.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 3000
sessionManager.request(.GET, url)
            .authenticate(user: user, password: password)
            .responseString { response in
                if (response.result.error != nil)
                {
                    show_error()
                }
            }
            .response { (request, response, data, error) in ...
```

You can find more about session managers in the [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#session-manager) file...

Comment: It is for Alamofire 4.0, but I use 3.0
For Alamofire 3.0: Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 300

Could you tell me please, where I need to input it code? I want to if timeout more then 3 sec to perform this function: show_error()

Comment: Well the timeout will surely through an error. So you handle it like one just as you would any other error.

Comment: Where I need add this code? I added in the viewDidLoad and it not work for me.